# issue with reversing characters in an array

Tags: c

i have an array here, a person's name which is inputted through keyboard, i have to reverse it but for some reason it say null whenever i run the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse_name(char *pointer, int length);

int main()
{//open main

    char name[20];
    int size;
    printf("enter name\n");
    scanf("%s", name);
    size  = strlen(name);
    reverse_name(name, size);

    return 0;
}//close main

void reverse_name(char *pointer, int length)
{//reverse open
    int i;
    for(i =0;i<length;i++)
    {//open for
        pointer[i] = pointer[length - i];
    }//close for

    printf("new name is %s", *pointer);
}//reverse close
```

Comment: `// open main // close main` -- please ***NOOOOO!***

Comment: Also, I'm wondering how much time you spent examining your program in a debugger.

Comment: @H2CO3, Oh but I do love when I see `//begin-if (some conditional)` ... `//end-if (something different)`  if I find out who teaches these things I won't go easy on him/her.

Comment: when i==0, pointer[length] == '\0' and also it be overwritten , not exchange.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
pointer[i] = pointer[length - i - 1];
```

you are actually considering a cell of the array that goes beyond its length.

Comment: Also, @Joachim's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
printf("new name is %s", *pointer);
```

Here you try to print a *single character* as a string. Drop the dereference operator.

Also, you actually reverse the string *twice*. Loop only *half* the string length.

Comment: Also, @Andrea's answer.

Answer (score 0):

fix exsample.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse_name(char *pointer, int length);

int main(void){
    char name[20];
    int size;
    printf("enter name\n");
    scanf("%19s", name);
    size  = strlen(name);
    reverse_name(name, size);
    printf("new name is %s", name);

    return 0;
}

void reverse_name(char *pointer, int length){
    int front = 0, back = length-1;
    while(front < back){
        char ch = pointer[front];
        pointer[front++] = pointer[back];
        pointer[back--]  = ch;
    }
}
```